# How exactly does operator <> work in Purescript?

Tags: type-conversion, purescript

Being new to Purescript, I am struggling to figure out why the following code (taken from "PureScript By Example") works as it does:

```
> flip (\n s -> show n <> s) "Ten" 10
"10Ten"
```

This makes sense to me: flip calls its first argument (the lambda expression) with its second and third argument in reverse order and so produces the concatenated string.

But I wonder why we get the following response with this snippet:

```
> flip (\n s -> show n <> s) 10 "Ten"

Could not match type Int with type String
```

Here is my line of thinking: operator `<>` which is actually a shorthand for `Data.Semigroup.append` is called with `n` deduced to `String` (an instance of `Data.Semigroup`) and `s` deduced to `Int`. So why can't `<>` append an `Int` to a `String` ? (I suppose because of it being right-associative, but am unsure ...)

Comment: `show n` turns `n` into a string. Thus the `<>` operator is resolved to be coming from the semigroup instance for strings. It expects two arguments of the same type, but in your second example `s` is `10`, which is not a string.

Comment: I wasn't aware of how operator precedence works here. See answer and comments below.

Comment: Nice one! It doesn’t have to do with precedence, rather the semantics of `flip`, which does what you did manually, I.e. flip the arguments of the given function. Because you flip twice (once with ˋflip` and once manually), you end up with an Int where a string is supposed to be... adding a signature to the lambda would have made that clear.

Comment: But if operator `<>` had precedence over function application the function body would effectively be `show (n <> s)` and so the first call would also not get compiled, right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear...

```
flip (\n s -> show n <> s) "Ten" 10  == show 10 <> "Ten"
flip (\n s -> show n <> s) 10 "Ten"  == show "Ten" <> 10
```

`(<>)` (an alias for `Data.Semigroup.append`) has the type:

```
append :: a -> a -> a
```

That is, it's arguments must be of the same type (they must *match*). But in your second call you're passing it a `String` and an `Int`, hence the type error.

This behaviour might be surprising if you're coming from a weakly typed language like javascript with implicit type coercion.

Comment: Right, but in my first call I'm also passing two different types, only in a different order: an `Int` and a `String`, so I'd suppose they don't match either.

Comment: Yes, but you're calling `show` which has the type `a -> String`, and  function application (prefix) has highest precedence. So in the first case your function body is effectively `(show n) <> s`

Comment: Now the penny has dropped. So its operator precedence that makes the first call legal.

Comment: To everybody who wants to learn about PureScript's type deduction mechanism: also have look at @The Unix Man's answer below

Answer (score 2):

So let's take this apart a bit. First, the original function:

```
flip (\n s -> show n <> s) "Ten" 10
```

If we take the type of each part, what do we see?

```
> :t flip
forall a b c. (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
```

This is really just `flip` of course, and it takes a two-parameter function and turns it into another one with the arguments flipped.

Next, and this is the interesting part, the `(a -> b -> c)` of `flip`, which becomes `b -> a -> c`:

```
> :t (\n s -> show n <> s)
forall t4. Show t4 => t4 -> String -> String
```

Ok, so, how does it come up with `t4 -> String -> String`? The only function in this one that references `String` specifically is `show`:

```
> :t show
forall a. Show a => a -> String
```

Also, this is where the `Show` constraint on `t4` comes from. What PureScript is telling us is that `(\n s -> show n <> s)` is a function, it takes two arguments, and returns a `String`.

It's calling our first argument `t4`, which is a valid and unique type variable for this session. It also can't tell us anything about `t4` except that since `show` requires an instance of `Show`, `t4` must be an instance of `Show`.

Now, calling `show` on our `Show => t4` will return a `String`, which we expect `show` to do:

```
> :t show
forall a. Show a => a -> String
```

(Yes, we saw this already.) So, inside our function `(\n s -> show n <> s)`, the `show n` term has type `String`. This is because `show` has been fully applied with `t4`, which is an instance of `Show`, and so the compiler can infer that `show n` will have the type of `show`, `String`.

Now this is where it gets interesting. `<>` in its most general form has a single type parameter:

```
> :t (<>)
forall a. Semigroup a => a -> a -> a
```

It's a function, and it takes two values of type `a`, and returns a new value of type `a`. Note how while the function has a type parameter, it only has one type parameter, so any particular `(<>)` will not be polymorphic in its types.

Now, while our function *is polymorphic* in its first parameter, it also only has a single type variable. This is actually a bit of a red herring anyway, because let's see what `flip` does:

```
> :t flip (\n s -> show n <> s)
forall t5. Show t5 => String -> t5 -> String
```

Woah. Our polymorphic parameter is still there, but now it's the second one. This is what `flip` does. So what does this mean, really?

```
> flip (\n s -> show n <> s) "Ten" 10
```

In this case, `"Ten"` is a `String`, which our `flip`ped function expects. `10` is, well, it's something:

```
> :t 10
Int
```

In this case it's an `Int`. Is `Int` an instance of `Show`?

```
> show (10 :: Int)
"10"
```

Yep! So, the values `"Ten"` and `10` satisfy the parameters of the `flip`ped function, `forall a. Show a => String -> a -> String`, where `"Ten"` is `String` and `10`, an `Int`, is an instance of `Show`.

Now, let's look at the failing case:

```
> flip (\n s -> show n <> s) 10 "Ten"
```

`"Ten"` is a `String`. Is `String` an instance of `show`?

```
> show "Ten"
"\"Ten\""
```

It is! Neat! So that's fine. Now, is `10` a `String`? Well, no, sadly, it's not. So `10` can't be used as the first argument to the `flip`ped function.